# C++ и Lua использование нескольких версий

Tags: c++, lua

Как можно использовать несколько версий Lua (например 5.2 и 5.3) в одном бинарнике? Если есть одна библиотека то она используется, если 2 или более - выбор. Как я понимаю надо вытащить все defin-ы из h-файлов и слинковать функции с помощью dlopen/dlsym

Comment: Много лет прошло, но всё же, обратите внимание на комментарий под ответом ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никогда не решал подобной задачи, но на ум приходит использование `boost::dll`. При помощи неё можно удобно открыть любую C-либу в C++ (технически, это обёртка над теми же `dlopen`/`dlsym` в ООП стиле).

P.S.: возможно, проще переписать lua-код под нужную версию (если это не сторонние расширения, конечно).

Comment: Помог ли Вам мой ответ?

Comment: ТС не получит уведомления при таком комментарии. Надо спросить под вопросом или, если он уже отметился в комментарии под сообщением, добавить его ник через `@`.

Comment: Прошло достаточно много времени, я уже точно не помню как была решена проблема. На сколько я помню, в проекте отсутсвовал boost и добавлять его не хотелось. Исходя из текущего кода ([проект заброшен](https://github.com/Zabqer/AurumEmulator/blob/master/src/architectures/lua/lua_lib.cpp)) я сделал обёртку над библиотечными функциями, но реализовал только для 5.3.